# pandas cumulative sum of stock in warehouse

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the warehouse stocks on different days

```
day action  quantity symbol
0   1         40      a
1   1         53      b
2   -1        21      a
3   1         21      b
4   -1         2      a
5   1         42      b
```

Here, `day` represents time series, `action` represents `buy/sell` for specific product (`symbol`) and of `quantity`.
For this dataframe, How do I calculate the cumulative sum daily, for each product.
Basically, a resultant dataframe as below:

```
days    a   b
0       40  0
1       40  53
2       19  53
3       19  64
4       17  64
5       17  106
```

I have tried cumsum() with groupby and was unsuccessful with it

Comment: In your `b` it is suppose to be 74 based on the sum . Right??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pivot_table`

```
In [920]: dff = df.pivot_table(
                   index=['day', 'action'], columns='symbol',
                   values='quantity').reset_index()
In [921]: dff
Out[921]:
symbol  day  action     a     b
0         0       1  40.0   NaN
1         1       1   NaN  53.0
2         2      -1  21.0   NaN
3         3       1   NaN  21.0
4         4      -1   2.0   NaN
5         5       1   NaN  42.0
```

Then, `mul` the action, take `cumsum`, forward fill missing values, and finally replace `NaN`s with `0`

```
In [922]: dff[['a', 'b']].mul(df.action, 0).cumsum().ffill().fillna(0)
Out[922]:
symbol     a      b
0       40.0    0.0
1       40.0   53.0
2       19.0   53.0
3       19.0   74.0
4       17.0   74.0
5       17.0  116.0
```

Final result

```
In [926]: dff[['a', 'b']].mul(df.action, 0).cumsum().ffill().fillna(0).join(df.day)
Out[926]:
      a      b  day
0  40.0    0.0    0
1  40.0   53.0    1
2  19.0   53.0    2
3  19.0   74.0    3
4  17.0   74.0    4
5  17.0  116.0    5
```

Comment: Nice solution +1.

Comment: Upvoted. Solved my problem. Info for the sake of the readers : In case day gets repeated (for another product) - i.e on same day two different transactions on different product occurs, then replace df.action with dff.action and df.day with dff.day to solve repeated row problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Nevermind, didn't see [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) tag. This is just plain Python.**

Try this:

```
sums = []

currentsums = {'a': 0, 'b': 0}

for i in data:
    currentsums[i['symbol']] += i['action'] * i['quantity']
    sums.append({'a': currentsums['a'], 'b': currentsums['b']})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDLDoMgFETX8hV3Rx@2UdtuTPwSwwIfTUkqUMSFMXw7hdQ2ahObbiAzOXcGruz1TfDEVlRTyCBHwYDbvinEHaeAKQ7dUWomuJOxE4@Ocs107@Q5MuEcL9bwy2mJz9MPCz6J/4r/xn/Er@PLvyYGEdt2TeuXRBAqO6VqrkdncNMpRKF/o7sNQlehgAHj4BebomDC5yx/1xIC@wycHnsJ7Lz6FBMU@IkjlbLm1eZVM41yBhlbZ3aBidlaqRjX4B37BA)

Note that it gives a different result than you posted because you calculated wrong.